# Avoid memory leaks with promises and loop in coffee-script (no await)

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am currently trying to perform some operations using promises in a loop but I ended up with huge memory leaks.

My problem is exactly the one pointed out in [this article](https://alexn.org/blog/2017/10/11/javascript-promise-leaks-memory.html) but as opposite to author, I am writing in coffee-script (yes, with hyphen. Which means coffeescript 1.12 and not the latest version). Thus, I am not able to use "await" key word (this is a casual guess since each time I want to use it, I got "await is not defined" error).

This is my original code (with memory leaks) :

```
recursiveFunction: (next = _.noop) ->

    _data = @getSomeData()

    functionWithPromise(_data).then (_enrichedData) =>

         @doStuffWithEnrichedData(_enrichedData)

         @recursiveFunction()

    .catch (_err) =>

         @log.error _err.message

         @recursiveFunction()
```

So according to the article I linked, I would have to do something like that :

```
recursiveFunction: (next = _.noop) ->

    _data = @getSomeData()

    _enrichedData = await functionWithPromise(_data)

    @recursiveFunction()
```

But then again, I am stuck because I can't use "await" key word. What would be the best approach then ?

EDIT:

Here is my real original code. What I am trying to achieve is a face-detection application. This function is located in a lib and I am using "Service" variable to expose variables between libs. In order to get frame from webcam, I am using opencv4nodejs.

```
faceapi = require('face-api.js')
tfjs = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')

(...)

# Analyse the new frame
analyseFrame: (next = _.noop) ->

    # Skip if not capturing
    return unless Service.isCapturing

    # get frame
    _frame = Service.videoCapture.getFrame()

    # get frame date, and
    @currentFrameTime = Date.now()

    # clear old faces in history
    @refreshFaceHistory(@currentFrameTime)


    #convert frame to a tensor
    try
        _data = new Uint8Array(_frame.cvtColor(cv.COLOR_BGR2RGB).getData().buffer)
        _tensorFrame = tfjs.tensor3d(_data, [_frame.rows, _frame.cols, 3])
    catch _err
        @log.error "Error instantiating tensor !!!"
        @log.error _err.message


    # find faces on frames
    faceapi.detectAllFaces(_tensorFrame, @faceDetectionOptions).then (_detectedFaces) =>

            @log.debug _detectedFaces

            # fill face history with detceted faces
            _detectedFaces = @fillFacesHistory(_detectedFaces)

            # draw boxes on image
            Service.videoCapture.drawFaceBoxes(_frame, _detectedFaces)

            # Get partial time
            Service.frameDuration = Date.now() - @currentFrameTime

            # write latency on image
            Service.videoCapture.writeLatency(_frame, Service.frameDuration)

            # show image
            Service.faceRecoUtils.showImage(_frame)

            # Call next
            _delayNextFrame = Math.max(0, 1000/@options.fps - Service.frameDuration)

            setTimeout =>
                # console.log "Next frame : #{_delayNextFrame}ms - TOTAL : #{_frameDuration}ms"
                @analyseFrame()
            , (_delayNextFrame)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! What are you trying to achieve in your original code? Inifinitely trying to call the same function, even when it errors is the problem, not the promises. This is the equivalent of the `await` version calling `recursiveFunction` in a `catch` block. `await` won't magically fix this. If you could give a simplified example of the various functions you are calling, and what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to better help you.

Comment: @Caffeinated.tech Thank you for your advises. I edited my post with my full original code.

Comment: I am less in less convinced that my memory leaks come from combination of loop and promise... I feel like it comes from detectAllFaces itself.

Comment: I agree - nothing with the promise looks wrong. Maybe you are running the `analyseFrame` too often for your system. Maybe the images are too large, or your fps value is too high. The service where you are displaying images may not be releasing images for GC too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to dispose the tensor copy sent to detectFaces.

```
faceapi.detectAllFaces(_tensorFrame, @faceDetectionOptions).then (_detectedFaces) =>
    (...)
    _tensorFrame.dispose()
    (...)
```